# yii framework how to create a multilanguage active record

Tags: activerecord, yii, internationalization, multilingual

How can I create a multilanguage active record in the Yii framework?
So in my CRUD -> create / update, I can enter e.g. the title in english and dutch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at internationalization:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n

By setting the language parameter in the config file you specify what language to use. Echo your content with

```
Yii::t('langfile','message to translate');
```

For translations from the database look at:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMessageSource

Once you have everything in place. You can create CRUD operations for the translations just like you could for other any other database table.

Tutorials/More info:

http://www.pintarprogramming.com/23/Yii-internationalization

http://learnyii.blogspot.nl/2010/12/yii-setting-up-internationalization.html

Comment: but this is not what I'm looking for, I need to be able to translate the content from a node inside the node crud, like every cms have

Comment: you can also use this with translations from the database. is that what you need?

Comment: I've edited the answer. Take a look at the `CDbMessageSource` class

Comment: thanks, do you know any tutorial on how to use this?

Comment: You should be able to figure it out with the CDbMessageSource page and the extra sites I've added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49956/discussion-between-ruben-and-jagsler)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used this class:
http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/multilingual-behavior/

And the CDbMessageSource solution